# Creating Threads within a Thread in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using the threading libary and want to have one thread that will call several threads. The background to this program is that I have a camera which captures Image and makes them available in a class on a TCP-SocketServer.

Thus I need one thread that runs the camera capturing and a second thread that runs the TCPServer, but within this Thread there are several Threads for each incoming connection.

This last thread means I  need a thread that can create threads on its own. Unfortunately this did not work.

I managed to break down the immense code into a small snippet which represents the problem:

```
import threading

def adder(x,res,i):
        res[i] = res[i] + x*i;

def creator(a,threads,results):
    results = []
    for i in range(0,a):
        results.append(0)
        threads.append(threading.Thread(target=adder,args=(a,results,i)))
        threads[i].start()
    for i in range(0,len(threads)):
        threads[i].join()

    return results;


threads = [];
results = [];

mainThread = threading.Thread(target=creator,args=([5,threads,results]))
mainThread.start()

mainThread.join()
for i in range(0,len(results)):
    print results[i]
    print threads[i]
```

In the function `creator` which is called as a thread there should be several threads created with the funciton `adder`.

However the results are empty, why is that so?

This is the same problem that occurs in my larger program.

Comment: Python threads have no such method (`.terminate()`) - regardless of whether they've been started.  See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python

Comment: Python threads have no `.stop()` method either - your edited code _should_ be raising an exception about that now.  See the link I already gave:  Python supports no builtin way to force threads to stop.

Comment: Strangely it worked. However I now replaced the thread to one that will just have a simple task and wait for all the threads to join , however the results are still empty and I get now the notification that NoneType has no function called join

Comment: You're appending the `start` return values to `threads`.

Comment: Thank you! That resolved this issue, but still nothing in the results :/

Comment: You're not waiting for `mainThread` to end, so the actual main thread charges full speed ahead, and you're probably printing `results` before any other threads have had a chance to get started.

Comment: D'oh, thank you! after putting mainthread.join() the result vector is still empty....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You got close! :-)

The problem in the latest version of the code is that, while the global `results` is passed to `creator()`, `creator()` never uses it:  it creates its own *local* `results` list.  Of course modifying the latter has no effect on the global `results`, so that one remains empty.  So here's a variation to repair that, but also with minor local changes to make the code more "Pythonic":

```
import threading

def adder(x, res, i):
    res[i] += x*i

def creator(a, threads, results):
    for i in range(a):
        results.append(0)
        t = threading.Thread(target=adder, args=(a, results, i))
        threads.append(t)
        t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

threads = []
results = []

mainThread = threading.Thread(target=creator, args=(5, threads, results))
mainThread.start()
mainThread.join()
for i in range(len(results)):
    print results[i]
    print threads[i]
```